# send data from template to views through javascript in django

Tags: python, django

I want to pass an array from `template` to `views` in Django.

`container = ['oppo find x, Mi 9']`

An array is creating by using javaScript.

now I want to pass the container to the views. how can I achieve that

here it's my code for passing data using ajax

```
 function submition(container){
   $.ajax({
        url :'/compare_in/',
        type : "POST",
        data : {
            cont : container,
        },
        success : function() {
            console.log('Success');
        },
        error : function() {
            console.log('Failure');
        }
    });

}

 function ComAction() {
var items = document.querySelectorAll('#list li');
           var container = [];
            for(var i=0;i<items.length;i++)
            {
                container.push(items[i].innerHTML);
            }
            submition(container)

        }
```

in my urls:

```
path('compare_in/', views.compare_in)
```

views:

```
def compare_in(request):
    print('done')
```

Comment: Use jquery ajax

Comment: I tried.. but not getting result

Comment: Show how you are pssing deta using ajax

Comment: I updated my question

Comment: Sho code of view as well

Comment: updated views...

Comment: What are you getting in request.body in your views?

Comment: I'm getting nothing but I want to get an Array